# ListPlot not plotting

Tags: plotting

Why does the following output from a Sow/Reap not plot?

```
{out, pts} = Reap[
...
EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{p}]]`

{{{-50}, {2}, {0}, {-50}, {2}, {0}, {2}, 
{-50}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {2}, \
{2}, {0}, {0}, {2}, {4}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{0}, {0}, {0}, {4}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {-50}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {2}, {2}, {2}, {2}, {2}, {2}}}

ListPlot[{p}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why all the curly braces? Just `Sow[p]` and then `ListPlot[pts]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ListPlot[p // Flatten]
```

[image]

to plot the values over indices

Comment: That works, but why doesn't it show the -50?

Comment: Just add `, PlotRange -> All`